# Specify acceleration of the parallel version

Tags: c#

It was necessary to write a parallel program for finding the number of common elements of two numerical arrays (which occur in both arrays), I executed it, but I still need to specify the acceleration of the parallel version. I need to parallelize this algorithm in ***int Spilnuy(object? param)*** please help

```
using System.Diagnostics;
   
    const int totalSize = 20_000;
    const int taskCount = 8;
    
    var array1 = new int[totalSize];
    var array2 = new int[totalSize];
    var spilnuy = new int[totalSize];
    var random = new Random();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = random.Next(2 * totalSize);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = random.Next(2 * totalSize);
    }
    
    
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    var globalMax = Spilnuy((array1, array2, 0, totalSize));
    watch.Stop();
    var durationSerial = watch.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine($"Serial mode: maximum coordinate is {globalMax}, duration is {durationSerial}");
    
    var tasks = new Task<int>[taskCount];
    var taskSize = totalSize / taskCount;
    
    watch.Restart();
    
    
    int Spilnuy(object? param)
    {
    
        int k = 0;
        if(param is (int[] array1, int[] array2, int from, int to))
        for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
        {
            foreach (int v in array2)
            {
                if (array1[i] == v)
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
```

Comment: If you are looking for the fast solution and `array2` is long, why not turn it into `HashSet<int>` and have `O(n)` time complexity vs. `O(n * m)`?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only go to parallel algorithms when you are *sure* you have exhausted all other ways to optimize the code. This example is trivial to optimize with a full `n` to `log n` reduction, (as Dmitry points out). This is a **much** greater improvement than reducing the time by however many cores you have, at least for any large arrays (and if they are not large, why bother).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the fast solution why not get rid of *nested* loops and use hashes:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int Spilnuy(object? param) {
  if (param is (int[] array1, int[] array2, int from, int to)) {
      HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(array1.Skip(from).Take(to - from + 1));

      return array2.Count(item => hs.Contains(item));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you insist on *parallel* you can try *PLinq* (Parallel Linq):

```
...
return array2.AsParallel().Count(item => hs.Contains(item));
...
```

or `Parallel.ForEach`

```
int Spilnuy(object? param) {
  if (param is (int[] array1, int[] array2, int from, int to)) {
      HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(array1.Skip(from).Take(to - from + 1));

      int result = 0;

      Parallel.ForEach(array2, item =>
      {
          if (hs.Contains(item))
              Interlocked.Increment(ref result);
      }); 

      return result;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how to parallelize it. I don't understand

Comment: @Boooeee: I doubt if you can get much gain from running the code in parallel; however, there are two options here:  PLinq (Parallel Linq) and `Parallel.ForEach`, please, see my edit.